# Camera2BasicFragment - problems modifying to switch front/back cameras

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-camera2

I'm trying to modify the Camera2BasicFragment sample project to support switching between the front and back cameras.
I added a switch button overlay on the preview screen, and the following code to handle the click. Also a class variable `cameraDirection` to remember which camera is currently in use:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_take_photo:
            takePicture();
            break;

        case R.id.button_reverse_camera:
            CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
            try {
                String[] cameraIds = manager.getCameraIdList();
                CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraId);
                for (String id : cameraIds) {
                    if (! id.equals(mCameraId)) {
                        closeCamera();
                        cameraDirection = cameraDirection == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT?CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_BACK:
                                CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT;
                        mCameraId = id;
                        openCamera(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
                    }
                }

            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

    }
}
```

The annoying thing is that the first switch of the camera works fine. But subsequent switches don't work. What happens is that the preview fades a little, like something is happening, but it remains on the currently selected camera. After a few more clicks on the switch button, the application crashes, and even more annoying is that there's no stack trace. So I've got no idea what the problem is.
I suspect a camera lock isn't being released properly, but that's just a guess.

So I'm hoping that someone has successfully modified this sample to handle camera switching, or can recommend an alternative Camera2 fragment implementation.

Comment: Hi Andrew, did you find a solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Project is on hold so I didn't pursue it further. Sorry.

Comment: @AndrewFielden Any updates ?

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb I'm afraid not. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the method `setUpCameraOutputs(int width, int height)` , where it sets `mCameraId=cameraId;`, because as it says in its comments

> // We don't use a front facing camera in this sample.

I tried with

```
if(mCameraId==null){
    mCameraId=cameraId;
}
```

but it's not enough because it does not set the preview size corrrectly for me.

You could modify the method to `setUpCameraOutputs(int width, int height, String cameraId)` and do the setup correctly.